# How to cut out corrupted parts of DVD-video extracted from disc so file can be played?

Tags: video, dvd

I have some unique footage that I unfortunately only have a corrupted DVD copy of. I have been able to use `gddrescue` on Linux to extract most of the footage, but when I play the video in `vlc` it stops playing at certain points, and `vlc` returns to the playlist view. If I manually skip to the part where `vlc` stopped playing and skip a little forward, say a few seconds, I can play the file again and it works.

**Is there a tool that I can use to automatically cut out the non corrupted parts of the video file so that I can play it without problem?**

---

What causes this problem, what's technically wrong with the DVD-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remuxing it will *probably* help, as the apps are generally smart enough to detect random crap and skip over it, as well as fix the timing information.

You didn't mention if it's a ripped as in copied direct MPEG-2 file or one ripped using HandBrake or something else.

Either way, use ffmpeg, avconv, or mkvmerge to remux them.

```
  ffmpeg (or avconv) -i source.mpg -codec copy dest.mkv
  mkvmerge -o dest.mkv source.mpg
```

Comment: Will test this at the next occasion!